# Angular: Use service from other module

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to import a service from outside a module.

The setup I have is as follows: I have this Foo module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        FooComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        FooComponent
    ],
    providers:[
        FooService
    ]
});
export class FooModule {}
```

which I import in `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [ FooModule ]
});
...
```

This works fine.

Next I want to import `FooService` from within `app.module.ts`, so I moved the line `providers: { FooService }` to `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [FooService],
    imports: [ FooModule ]
});
...
```

So far the app still works. The final step, I copied the service file outside the foo directory, I changed the import path, I even restarted the server and now I get an error in the browser

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: No provider for FooService!
```

It cannot find the service anymore.

Any suggestions why the service is missing when the service file is not in the foo directory ? And can this be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried following solution. It's working for me :

**Foo Module**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        FooComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        FooComponent
    ],
});
export class FooModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {Fooservice} from './FooService';
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [ FooModule ]
    providers: [FooService],
});
...
```

**Foo.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FooService }       from '../FooService'; 

@Component({

})
export class FooComponent {

    constructor(public fooservice: FooService) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You're correct, this does work, thanks, It turned out I forgot to remove an import in an other file after I refactored :(